Why do cellular dongles lose internet connectivity?
I have a Pi Zero device that needs to send periodic updates from remote locations. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to have a USB cellular dongle and send the data via email. This does work - in principle - but very often the device loses internet connectivity for hours on end. I first tried with a simple commercial K1561z dongle and sim (Vodafone in the UK), setting the provider's APN, but when it stops working, there's nothing that can provide diagnostics when things aren't working. The most I can do is ping programatically and reboot if there's no response (but that never solves the problem). With a more sophisticated modem (SIM7600G-H) I can interrogate the APN registration, and it's fine - but still there's just no response to pinging.
I saw this thread How does APN affect cellular connectivity? which implies that the network or the tower can disconnect the internet at any time, but that seems a little odd. Yesterday, for instance, I could only send emails from 00:00 until 02:45 ‍♂️. What I really need is a way to diagnose this and see why I don't have internet and what to do about it. Any ideas?
[2024-08-09] Thanks for all the comments. Oh my! It doesn't sound promising. So my follow up questions are:

A consumer dongle appears as eth0. Is there any way at all to perform diagnostics (other than ping)? Because all the possible problem sources that people have described are very different.
If I use a dongle that appears as usb0, I can issue AT commands, but does that give me any ability to diagnose the problem, other than checking that the APN is registered and connected (it is)?
[More of a comment than a question] You say that hard power cycling may be necessary (I've just been doing sudo reboot now). I might try that.


That is such a broad topic and much of it might be out of your control. My approach? I'd start w/the RPi's power supply. Many times people under power the RPi's and they behave in unexpected ways. Next I would consider electrical noise/interference. Are there any electric motors or solenoids near by? Then I would consider things that block radio signals. Is the device inside a car, truck, metal structure, metal roof or rebar? Finally, different carriers may use different cell towers. Try a differ carrier. Or try a different cell-phone technology.

Lots of cellular modems sadly have quite a few stability problems, which may vary based on firmware version, technology or even band used, carrier settings, modem settings (like power saving modes, for instance)… Many dongles have had testing only in “consumer” scenarios (often plugged in/out, powered off, manual connection…). Most are notoriously hard to debug. Issues may occur at different places (radio, IP, NAT…), and many networks may have all sorts of timeouts (especially those targeting consumers). Maybe dedicated data-only providers will get you a better result. What country are you in?

Providers often take down internet, cellular more do for a variety of reasons such as maintenance. And something could be wrong with your software, pi, the power supply or the dongle.
I have used two solutions in the past, for my Iot hardware.

Brute force approach. Put a timer on the mains and restart it periodically.

In your software. Ping a site such as google  periodically. If there is no response, activate    a timed relay to restart your device. IYou need a hardware reset.


The 3rd one, that I am still working on is to auto repower my device when it hasnt accessed a slave device for a period of time.
